# If every subset in a topological space is closed, prove it is a discrete space

Tags: general-topology

This is question from [Topology without tears](http://www.topologywithouttears.net/topbook.pdf) by [S. Morris](http://uob-community.ballarat.edu.au/~smorris/index.htm). It reads;

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space with the property that every subset is closed. Prove that it is a discrete space.

I actually think it's not true though, my counter example:

$$let\quad X = \{x, y\}\quad and \quad \tau = \{\emptyset, X\} $$

Cleary $\tau$ is a topology and all it's subsets are closed, but it's not a discrete space. What am I missing?

Comment: $\{x\}$ is not closed under your topology. Its complementary, $\{y\}$, is indeed not open.

Comment: To answer your question, because every subset is closed, every subset is also open. In particular, the singletons are open. This is the very definition of the discrete topology.

Comment: Ahh I see, sorry that seems so obvious now.

Comment: I feel it's answered already. What do I do with the question now, just keep it up?

Comment: @MatticeVerhoeven: You should accept the answer.

Comment: I thought of trying to prove it by induction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If every subset of $X$ is closed, then every subset of $X$ is open! Hence $ \tau$ is the discrete topology on $X$. In your example not every subset of $X$ is closed (e.g. $\{x\}$).